# My unity project gives error when i try to open it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use Unity Hub 3.3.0 and 2022.1.23f1 editor version[image: gives this error]

How can I open a unity project for Mac?

Comment: Try to delete the Library folder and open Unity again... it's hard to tell, you didn't provide information enough in order to figure out a reason for that.

Comment: Thanks; I just uploaded it, when I try to create a new project I got this error. I want to create the project as 2D core.

Comment: Could you please provide your log information.

Comment: file:///Users/macbookpro/Library/Application%20Support/UnityHub/logs/info-log.json

Comment: We cannot access your local hard-drive. If you tried to drag and drop the file in to the StackOverflow section then it doesn't work this way. You try can copy the contents of that file and paste them as text in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, probably the part in the photo where the error is, I think the troubleshooting steps you wrote
unopened file
more
solutions that can be applied if it is a file that has been opened before, but I have not been able to open a file since I first uploaded it.[image: ][1]]

Comment: Please *never* give code/errors/... as image!